# Change properties of mediaelement in different wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, window, mediaelement

in my app i have 2 different wpf windows. the main window has some buttons and textboxes to control a medielement in a different window.

**how can i control the mediaelement in window2 from window1?**

For example I press button_play in window1 and the filename ist readed out from textbox1 in window1 and the source property of the mediaelement in window2 is set (from textbox1 value) and medialement.play.

Thanks SMerker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways of doing this by the simplest one would probably be to expose the `MediaElement` in `Window2`, either by using the `x:FieldModifier` attribute in XAML or by defining a property in the code-behind:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="me" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

You could then get a reference to `Window2` using the `Application.Current.Windows` property and access the generated backing field or property directly:

```
Window2 win = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window2>().FirstOrDefault();
if (win != null)
    win.me.Source = ...;
```